# Add 6 hours to NOW function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I used the following formula to retrieve the timestamp.

> =IF(E2="Done",NOW(),"")

I need to add 6 hours to this timestamp. Is there a way to do this or do I need to use another function?

Comment: It would be much better to use VBA for this, if you want the timestamp to remain fixed. Otherwise, `NOW()+TIME(6,0,0)`?

Comment: I see what you mean. I would like to avoid VBA. Additionally, if cell E2 is not marked"Done" how do I avoid getting the result "#VALUE!" ?

Comment: IF E2 is not "Done", then the formula returns a blank string. Some detail from your question is missing, if you're getting a `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: Excuse me, the formula that is giving me the errror is as follows:=IF(E26="Done",NOW(),"")+TIME(6,0,0)

Comment: `=IF(E26="Done",NOW()+TIME(6,0,0),"")` you cannot add a time to a `""` which the IF returns when E26 <> "Done"

Comment: If the value is done it returns the value you want, but if anything changes in the workbook (anywhere in the document) it will recalculate (volatile function). Not only will this slow down your file, if you use a this on a whole range, for instance, it will also keep changing it to the next "now" + 6 hours. Therefore the only solution to lock the value is to use VBA. Anyway; `=NOW()+0.25` would return the value. 0.25 being 6 hours divided by 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
IF(E2="Done",NOW()+(6/24),"")
```

The (6/24) is because now() + 1 adds 24 hours. The cell is formatted as time.[image]